# Cycle through MeshStyle directives in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to specify my own mesh styles for successive data rows within a single `ListLinePlot`. The Wolfram reference for [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) lists [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) as options for `ListLinePlot`. Both options' refrence pages state that

> successive directives g<sub>i</sub> should be used cyclically

This works fine for `PlotStyle`, but not for `MeshStyle`. The following was run on Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Linux:

```
ListLinePlot[{
  Table[1/n + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]/n, {n, 1, 20}],
  Table[1/n, {n, 1, 20}]
  },
  Mesh -> All,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  MeshStyle -> {Yellow, Green}
]
```

With this output:

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = {Table[1/n + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]/n, {n, 1, 20}], Table[1/n, {n, 1, 20}]};
```

Assuming that you want different mesh styles for points on different lines (with default setting for the option `MeshFunctions`, that is, `{#&}`), you can

1. Combine two separate plots using `Show`:

```
Show[MapThread[ListLinePlot[#, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> #2, MeshStyle -> #3]&, {data, {Red, Blue}, {Yellow, Green}}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

2. Post-process the output of a single `ListLinePlot` to change the
   colors of points:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[data,  Mesh -> All,
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, MeshStyle -> {Yellow, Green}, PlotRange -> All];
meshstyles = Reverse @ { Yellow, Green};
llp /. p_Point :> {First[meshstyles = RotateRight[meshstyles]], p}
```

> same picture

3. Use a `Dynamic` mesh style:

```
meshstyles = Reverse @ {Yellow, Green};
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All,
  MeshStyle -> Dynamic[First[meshstyles = RotateRight[meshstyles]]]]
```

> same picture

4. Use a function as the `MeshStyle` setting:

```
meshstyles = Reverse @ {Yellow, Green};
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh ->All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},PlotRange -> All,
  MeshStyle -> ({First[meshstyles = RotateRight[meshstyles]],
    PointSize[Large], #}&)]
```

> same picture

All the methods above work with arbitrary number of data  rows:

```
n = 10;
meshstyles = Reverse [ ColorData[70] /@ Range[n]];
plotstyles = ColorData[97] /@ Range[n];
SeedRandom[1]
data = MapThread[Plus, {5 + Range[n], (Accumulate /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 15}])}];

ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All,  ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> plotstyles,
 MeshStyle -> ({First[meshstyles = RotateRight[meshstyles]], PointSize[Large], #} &), 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, Range[n], LegendMarkers -> 
   (Graphics[{#, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}] & /@ Reverse[meshstyles])]]
```

[image]

Comment: The styles rotation can be simplified by dropping `Reverse@{...}` and using `{Last[meshstyles = RotateLeft[meshstyles]], #} &`. Setting the `PointSize` is not necessary.

Comment: @DLichti, thank you; great point. Will update with an edit.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in order for `MeshStyle` to cycle through the list, you have to have more than one mesh, and this is determined by the number of `MeshFunctions` you have. By default, this is set to

```
MeshFunctions -> {#1&}
```

for `ListLinePlot`. If you add

```
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}
```

to your plot, `Yellow` will be used for the horizontal mesh, and `Green` for the vertical mesh, e.g.

```
SeedRandom[15];
ListLinePlot[{Table[1/n + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]/n, {n, 1, 20}], 
  Table[1/n, {n, 1, 20}]}, Mesh -> {5, 7}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Yellow, Green}]
```

[image]